# Как сократить код событий?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код:

```
$('.a1').mouseover(function () {
    $('svg .p1').addClass('op')
});
$('.a1').mouseout(function () {
    $('svg .p1').removeClass('op')
});

$('.a2').mouseover(function () {
    $('svg .p2').addClass('op')
});
$('.a2').mouseout(function () {
    $('svg .p2').removeClass('op')
});

$('.a3').mouseover(function () {
    $('svg .p3').addClass('op')
});
$('.a3').mouseout(function () {
    $('svg .p3').removeClass('op')
});
```

Как видно, код однообразный, растут только цифры после '.a*' и 'svg .p*' в селекторе.

Пытался сделать через цикл for (но я уже забыл, как там функции разные себя ведут, и как обрабатывать функции после инициализации (вроде, экспрешин функции называются, которые задаются через равно)). Пробовал через делегирование в js (есть ли такое в jquery?).

Вот одна из моих попыток:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= pLength; i++) {

    var a = '.a'+i;
    var p = 'svg .p'+i;

    $(a).mouseover(function () {
        alert(a)
        $(p).addClass('op')
    });
    $(a).mouseout(function () {
        alert(a)
        $(p).removeClass('op')
    });

}
```

Надеюсь идея ясна. Суть в размножении этого участка кода (менять только цифры после селекторов):

```
$('.a1').mouseover(function () {
    $('svg .p1').addClass('op')
});
$('.a1').mouseout(function () {
    $('svg .p1').removeClass('op')
});
```

Comment: Известно ли как .p1 и .a1 находятся друг относительно друга? Можно ли нагами К родителю и к следующему, предыдущему, поиск по дочерним определить $('svg .p2') отталкиваясь от $('.a2')?

Answer (score 3):

В Вашем цикле, переменные `a` и  `p` к моменту выполнения обработчиков событий `mouseover` и `mouseout` будут иметь значения, соответствующие последнему значению `i`.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= pLength; i++) {
  var a = '.a' + i;

  $(a).mouseover((function (iter) {
    return function() {
      alert('.a' + iter);
      $('svg .p' + iter).addClass('op');
    };
  })(i));

  $(a).mouseout((function (iter) {
    return function() {
      alert('.a' + iter);
      $('svg .p' + iter).removeClass('op');
    };
  })(i));
}
```

Comment: Хм, а как по-русски "closure"?

Comment: @Igor, изначально, в глоссариях MS и IBM, слово это переводилось как "замкнутое выражение" - собственно до середины 2000-х именно так и переводили практически всегда. Потом кто-то использовал перевод слова "closure" из математики, означающий совсем другое... Ну и как-то пошло в народ, распространилось, да так что старый перевод почти и не встретишь уже.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо, суть понял. Все работает! Добра вам!

Comment: @Igor: хотел добавить, что имя метода можно сохранить в переменную или параметр функции и использовать ее при вызове. За счет этого можно дополнительно сократить код. Например, `var addOrRemove = "removeClass"; .... $('svg .p' + iter)[addOrRemove]('op');`. Другой момент - можно формировать селектор и запяпыми ($(".a1,a2,a3,a5"), и использовать один `mouseover` и один `mouseout`

Comment: @Igor: для последнего шага необходимо знать относительное расположение `.a1` и `.p1`. Оно не указано в вопросе, но наверняка существует и можно использовать `this` и `.closest`

Comment: @Oleg - Согласен, all good points.